# Get the sum of the first index value of an array and array's length using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

"Given an array, print or log the sum of the first value in the array, plus the array’s length. Assume that the array is composed of numbers."

I have already formulated a javascript, my goal is to iterate on each dataArray and print the sum of each dataArray. The current script only outputs the sum of the dataArray1. Hope anyone can help on this. Thanks in advance!

```js
// Enter code below
var sum =0;
var numList = [];

var dataArray1=[1,2,5];  // to print 4
var dataArray2=[3,0,2,5];// to print 7
var dataArray3=[-5,0,2,5];// to print -1
var dataArray4=[1]; // to print 2

for (let i=0; i<=4; i++){
if (!numList.length){
  numList.push.apply(numList, dataArray1);
var listLength = numList.length;
var firstNum = numList[0];
}
sum = listLength + firstNum;
}
console.log(sum);
//the expected log/print should be 4, 7, -1, 2
```

Comment: I'm really struggling to understand "however I was stuck on how to have a counter check in order to log/print the output/answer.". You are logging the answer (for dataArray1 anyway); what is the counter you mention, what would it be checking, and how would that affect the log/print of the output?

Comment: Do you mean to iterate over each of the data arrays? Something like `for (const array of [dataArray1, dataArray2, dataArray3, dataArray4]) { //... your logic }`? see [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). Keep in mind that your `console.log` is currently outside of your loop so it will only ever log the last assignment to `sum`

Comment: @BenStephens , sorry about that.  My end goal is to iterate on each dataArray and print the sum of each dataArray. the expected log/print should be 4, 7, -1, 2.  thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function to make the sum between first item and length then append the resulted number to your array

```js
// Enter code below
let numList = [];

const dataArray1 = [1, 2, 5]; // to print 4
const dataArray2 = [3, 0, 2, 5]; // to print 7
const dataArray3 = [-5, 0, 2, 5]; // to print -1
const dataArray4 = [1]; // to print 2

// create a function and insert in numList the sum resulted
function returnSum(arr) {
  const listLength = arr.length;
  const firstNum = arr[0];

  let sum = listLength + firstNum;
  numList.push(sum);

  return sum;
}

// run the function for each array
returnSum(dataArray1);
returnSum(dataArray2);
returnSum(dataArray3);
returnSum(dataArray4);

console.log(numList)
```

EDIT

Based on your comment " I was planning to log the sum separately and not on a single array"

```js
// Enter code below
let numList = [];

const dataArray1 = [1, 2, 5]; // to print 4
const dataArray2 = [3, 0, 2, 5]; // to print 7
const dataArray3 = [-5, 0, 2, 5]; // to print -1
const dataArray4 = [1]; // to print 2

// create a function and return the sum
function returnSum(arr) {
  const listLength = arr.length;
  const firstNum = arr[0];

  return listLength + firstNum;
}

// run the function for each array
console.log(returnSum(dataArray1));
console.log(returnSum(dataArray2));
console.log(returnSum(dataArray3));
console.log(returnSum(dataArray4));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var dataArray1=[1,2,5];  // to print 4
var dataArray2=[3,0,2,5];// to print 7
var dataArray3=[-5,0,2,5];// to print -1
var dataArray4=[1]; // to print 2

let process=[dataArray1,dataArray2,dataArray3,dataArray4]

for (let i=0; i<process.length; i++)
    console.log(process[i][0]+process[i].length);
```

OR

```
var dataArray1=[1,2,5];  // to print 4
var dataArray2=[3,0,2,5];// to print 7
var dataArray3=[-5,0,2,5];// to print -1
var dataArray4=[1]; // to print 2


console.log([dataArray1,dataArray2,dataArray3,dataArray4].map((arr) =>console.log(arr[0]+arr.length)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, however I was planning to log the sum separately and not on a single array, if that make sense. On each iteration if dataArray, it should return the sum one by one. Sorry english is not my first language.

Comment: I updated the output please check it.

Answer (score 2):

```
function sum(arr) {
  return arr[0] + arr.length;
}
```

Then, you can pass in any array you like to this function.

Answer (score 2):

Tricky way, for browsers:

```js
var dataArray1 = [1, 2, 5]; // to print 4
var dataArray2 = [3, 0, 2, 5]; // to print 7
var dataArray3 = [-5, 0, 2, 5]; // to print -1
var dataArray4 = [1]; // to print 2

function trickySum(prefix) {
  var sum = 0;
  var numList = [];
  var i = 1;

  while (window[`${prefix}${i}`]) {
    numList = window[`${prefix}${i}`];
    i++;
    var listLength = numList.length;
    var firstNum = numList[0];
    sum = listLength + firstNum;
    console.log(sum);
  }
}

trickySum('dataArray');
```